# Device Tree and code size

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, device-tree

As per my understanding of **device trees**, one of main uses is to remove platform specific code from drivers to support multiple platforms. How does **device tree** handle multiple configuration for a single peripheral?

For example if I want to use LCD Panel A in Platform A and LCD Panel B in Platform B, do I need to keep both LCD Panel A and Panel B related code in the final binary?  If that is the case and there are multiple peripherals with more than one option, it seems there will be huge additional code in the binary.

Comment: you can have different dtsi files for two different panels and include it in respective dts files for 2 platforms. In this way, you can reduce the size of bloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose consider if you have 5 LCD panels and 5 platform(machines), keep 5 dtsi files each for each panel and have different dtsi files for each platform/machine.

**For single configuration:**
Include particular dtsi panel file inside dtsi file of particular platform/machine of your interest.
**Outcome:**
  - By this way you don't have to pass all the panel configurations and on-off LCD options in your board file. In simple you don't have to create separate board files for your new machine,instead have multiple device tree files and include any one of your interest during build.

**For multiple configuration:**
you can add n panel dtsi files inside your machine dtsi file of interest.
and by enabling/disabling particular lcd panel in defconfig file you can have any LCD panel driver enabled at run-time.
**Outcome:**
 - By this way , you avoid 1000 panel configurations added in single board file(you know how messy it is), Instead have 1000 dtsi files and add 1000 dt header panel files inside machine dt file and raise particular panel flag in defconfig. this will ease the job.
In simple- single board file and dtb containing all the files. reduces overall kernel size.

Answer (score 6):

> For example if I want to use LCD Panel A in Platform A and LCD Panel B in Platform B, So do I need to keep both LCD Panel A and Panel B related code in the final binary?

There are three cases for drivers.

1. Completely different chip and bus/sub-system.
2. Same bus/sub-system, but different chip set.
3. Same bus/sub-system, same chip set, different parameters.

From this you should understand the answer.  For an LCD, the **driver** is usually hosted on the SOC and the *panel* just changes parameters such as display geometry (1/4 VGA versus 1/2 VGA), timing (50Hz versus 75HZ) and possibly control signals (OE active low/high, active/passive matrix, etc).  This is actually handled exceptionally well by the **device tree** concept.

Prior to **device tree**, a *machine file* would pass *platform data* to the driver; this contains the parameters mentioned above.  As the *machine file* is code, both versions must be contained in the kernel for *panel A* and *panel B*.  This is not too bad, but for Ubuntu type releases with 1000s of *panels*, this can be an issue.  Previously the *boot loader* passed a single *machine id* and this keyed which *machine file* to use.  Now, the *device tree* is passed by the boot loader and the *machine file* is generally converted to a *device tree* structure.

Now, if the machine has different *Ethernet* controller chips, you can use both *device trees* and modules to keep the kernel size down. This is the 2<sup>nd</sup> case mentioned above.

The 3<sup>rd</sup> case can also be handled with *modules*.  For instance, a *wifi* driver and an *HSDPA* modem may be communication mechanisms on different platforms.  The **802.11** sub-system can be a module and can the *n-gsm* code.  Further, the *HSDPA* modem may use USB or a UART, whereas the *wifi* may use *SPI* or *SDIO*.  Some of this code may not be able to be convert modules as it may have some tight coupling with the network stack.  Generally every effort is made to minimize this overhead.

So generally, the *device tree* concept is actually reducing code; at least in SDRAM which is a primary resource that is at a premium.  NAND flash or other bulk storage may be bigger.  You have the option to statically configure the device for a specific piece of hardware.  If you intend to support both *panels* in one image, then *device trees* are better.  In fact, they are better in almost all cases.

Comment: Hi..can you explain the first scenario a little bit more ? As you mentioned that for ubuntu there will be 1000s of panels, so even if I am using the device tree concept, I will be just converting the board file to device tree structure... so how is it good ?(as you suggested device tree handle this exceptionally well.. so I want to know how does it do so good ?

Comment: The *device tree* can be *per boot loader*; so only the *boot loader* is specialized.  This does not apply if you link the *device tree* to the kernel image.  Also, as it is a data structure, it is easier to release it after the *init* phase.  All code in a **machine file** (old style) needs to be marked *init* or it will not be discarded, consuming non-swappable kernel memory.