# How does device tree support for two different LCD panel in the same binary?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am having confusion with device tree concept. As device tree is used, so that same kernel can be flashed on the different device (which are compatible).

Now suppose I want to use two different LCD panel for same project, So do I need to build the binary for different panel separately or I can create a single binary for this? 
If single binary, how can I do it ?

Comment: *"I want to use two different LCD panel"* -- What does "different" mean with respect to the software?  Are they so "different" that they have unique drivers?  Or do they share a common driver that can be configured at run-time?  *"build the binary"*  -- What binary are you referring to?  The DTB? The zImage or uImage? Or **.o**  or **.ko** files?

Comment: Well, I am not so sure but been in a situation where I have to provide support for two different on chip eeprom Devices and all I did was had two different entries for eeprom devices in single device tree file and used the single Linux kernel image to boot up.

Comment: @sawdust different means different vendor is providing panel(HW).. so obviously their settings will be different, for that reason only I want two different dts file not two different driver. Binary means finally compiled source which have all dtb files, so in here it will be zImage only.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar can you elaborate more, I really need to understand it.

Comment: @Rahul on our SoC we had two eeprom devices(differ in part number) sitting on i2c  bus.Our SoC is represented by One device tree which has these eeprom enteries under i2c parent node.Are you using appended device tree blob to zImage? Also,You need to maintain one dts file and dtsi for include files.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar I am also having two different dtsi file for my panel, but I am not able to understand how should I put the entries these two entries in main dts file ? currently for single file, we are defining the node in main dts file, and keeping it as status="ok", so what should I do for second panel file ?

Comment: A DTB represent a system configuration.  If you build a system with panel_A then you need a `sysA.dtb`.  If you build a system with panel_B then you need a `sysB.dtb`.  You should be able to build and use one kernel (z or u)Image file.  Attaching the dtb to the uImage file will cause a minor build and install issue, and should be avoided.  DT **overlay** might be an alternate solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device Tree and code size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546603/device-tree-and-code-size)